# Visualforce Delete Row: Missing id at index: 0

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have a visualforce page where users add and deletes records in a table. My only issue is if a user hits add row then decides to delete that row(therefore the record was never in the database) and hits save for any other changes I get the error: Missing id at index: 0.

How can I fix this thanks

Visualforce Page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Pre_Clarification__c" extensions="AddPositions" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
   <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 500px;">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Assets & Liabilities" id="pb" >
      <apex:pageMessages />      
      <apex:variable var="rowNumber1" value="{!0}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable" title="Secured Liabilities" var="prop" value="{!PropertyList}">
          <apex:column headerValue="Secured Liabilities" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!prop.Name}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Asset Amount" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!prop.Asset_Amount__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Liability Amount" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!prop.Liability_Amount__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Interest Rate" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!prop.Interest_Rate__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Structure" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!prop.Structure__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Repayment Amount" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!prop.Repayment_Amount__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Repayment Rate" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!prop.Repayment_Rate__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Fixed or Variable" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!prop.Fixed_or_Variable__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Loan Split" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!prop.Loan_Split__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column style="width:15%"/>
          <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow1}" reRender="pb">
              <apex:param name="rowIndex1" value="{!rowNumber1}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber1" value="{!rowNumber1+1}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow1}" value="Add Secured Liability" reRender="pb"/>
      <apex:variable var="rowNumber2" value="{!0}"/>
       <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable2" title="Unsecured Liabilities" var="liab" value="{!LiabilityList}">
          <apex:column headerValue="Unsecured Liabilities" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!liab.Name}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Liability Amount" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!liab.Liability_Amount__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Interest Rate" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!liab.Interest_Rate__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Structure" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!liab.Structure__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Repayment Amount" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!liab.Repayment_Amount__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Repayment Rate" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!liab.Repayment_Rate__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column style="width:25%"/>
          <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow2}" reRender="pb">
              <apex:param name="rowIndex2" value="{!rowNumber2}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber2" value="{!rowNumber2+1}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow2}" value="Add Unsecured Liability" reRender="pb"/>   
      <apex:variable var="rowNumber3" value="{!0}"/>
      <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable3" title="Assets" var="asset" value="{!AssetList}">
          <apex:column headerValue="Assets" style="width:17%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!asset.Name}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Asset Amount" style="width:15%">
            <apex:inputField value="{!asset.Asset_Amount__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column style="width:73%"/>
          <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow3}" reRender="pb">
              <apex:param name="rowIndex3" value="{!rowNumber3}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber3" value="{!rowNumber3+1}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow3}" value="Add Asset" reRender="pb"/>           
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel1}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>           
    </apex:pageBlock>
        </div>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Extension:

```
public class AddPositions {
    public Pre_Clarification__c PreClarifications;
    public RecordType PropDebtRecType;
    public RecordType LiabilityRecType;
    public RecordType AssetRecType;
    public Asset_Liabilities_Position__c del1;
    public Asset_Liabilities_Position__c del2;
    public Asset_Liabilities_Position__c del3;
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > addPropertyList {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > PropertyList {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > addLiabilityList {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > LiabilityList {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > addAssetList {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > AssetList {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > delPropDebtList {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > delPropDebt {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > delLiabilityList {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > delLiability {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > delAssetList {get;set;}
    public List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > delAsset {get;set;}
    public Integer totalCount1 {get;set;}
    public Integer totalCount2 {get;set;}
    public Integer totalCount3 {get;set;}
    public Integer rowIndex1 {get;set;}
    public Integer rowIndex2 {get;set;}
    public Integer rowIndex3 {get;set;}
    public List < Contact > delContacts {get;set;}

    public AddPositions(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            PreClarifications = (Pre_Clarification__c ) controller.getRecord();
            PropDebtRecType = [Select Id from RecordType where sObjecttype = 'Asset_Liabilities_Position__c' AND Name = 'Secured Liability'];
            LiabilityRecType = [Select Id from RecordType where sObjecttype = 'Asset_Liabilities_Position__c' AND Name = 'Unsecured Liability'];
            AssetRecType = [Select Id from RecordType where sObjecttype = 'Asset_Liabilities_Position__c' AND Name = 'Asset'];
            PropertyList = [select Id, Name, Asset_Amount__c, Interest_Rate__c, Liability_Amount__c, Related_Pre_Clarification__c, Repayment_Amount__c,
                                Repayment_Rate__c, Structure__c, Fixed_or_Variable__c, Loan_Split__c
                                 from Asset_Liabilities_Position__c where Related_Pre_Clarification__c = : PreClarifications.Id   
                                  AND RecordTypeId =: PropDebtRecType.Id                 
                                 ORDER BY Name ASC, Asset_Amount__c DESC NULLS LAST, Liability_Amount__c DESC];
            LiabilityList = [select Id, Name, Asset_Amount__c, Interest_Rate__c, Liability_Amount__c, Related_Pre_Clarification__c, Repayment_Amount__c, 
                                Repayment_Rate__c, Structure__c, Fixed_or_Variable__c, Loan_Split__c
                                 from Asset_Liabilities_Position__c where Related_Pre_Clarification__c = : PreClarifications.Id   
                                  AND RecordTypeId =: LiabilityRecType.Id                
                                  ORDER BY Name ASC];
            AssetList = [select Id, Name, Asset_Amount__c, Interest_Rate__c, Liability_Amount__c, Related_Pre_Clarification__c, Repayment_Amount__c, 
                                Repayment_Rate__c, Structure__c, Fixed_or_Variable__c, Loan_Split__c
                                 from Asset_Liabilities_Position__c where Related_Pre_Clarification__c = : PreClarifications.Id   
                                  AND RecordTypeId =: AssetRecType.Id               
                                  ORDER BY Name ASC];                                            
            totalCount1 = PropertyList.size();
            totalCount2 = LiabilityList.size();
            totalCount3 = AssetList.size();
            delPropDebtList = new List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > ();
            delPropDebt = new List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > ();
            delLiabilityList = new List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > ();
            delLiability = new List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > ();
            delAssetList = new List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > ();
            delAsset = new List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c > ();
    }

    public void addRow1() {
            addPropertyList = new List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c> ();
            PropertyList.add(new Asset_Liabilities_Position__c(Related_Pre_Clarification__c = PreClarifications.Id, RecordTypeId = PropDebtRecType.Id));
    }
    public void addRow2() {
            addLiabilityList = new List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c> ();
            LiabilityList.add(new Asset_Liabilities_Position__c(Related_Pre_Clarification__c = PreClarifications.Id, RecordTypeId = LiabilityRecType.Id));
    }
    public void addRow3() {
            addAssetList = new List < Asset_Liabilities_Position__c> ();
            AssetList.add(new Asset_Liabilities_Position__c(Related_Pre_Clarification__c = PreClarifications.Id, RecordTypeId = AssetRecType.Id));
    }

    public PageReference save() {
            try{
            upsert PropertyList;
            upsert LiabilityList;
            upsert AssetList;
            delete delPropDebtList;
            delete delLiabilityList;
            delete delAssetList;
            //return (new ApexPages.StandardController(accounts)).view();
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/Related_Asset_Liabilities');
            pageRef.getParameters().put('id',PreClarifications.Id);
            return pageRef;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                 ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            }
            return null;
    }
    public PageReference cancel1() {
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/Related_Asset_Liabilities');
            pageRef.getParameters().put('id',PreClarifications.Id);
            return pageRef;
    }
    public void deleteRow1() {
                rowIndex1 = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex1'));
                del1 = PropertyList.remove(rowIndex1);
                delPropDebtList.add(del1);
    }
    public void deleteRow2() {
            rowIndex2 = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex2'));
            del2 = LiabilityList.remove(rowIndex2);
            delLiabilityList.add(del2);
    }
    public void deleteRow3() {
            rowIndex3 = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex3'));
            del3 = AssetList.remove(rowIndex3);
            delAssetList.add(del3);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that no-database-saved items are being added to your 'delete' lists.

You should validate that, before add an item to your 'delete' lists, the item is a valid record saved in database:

```
public void deleteRowN() {
    rowIndexN = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndexN'));
    delN = PropertyList.remove(rowIndexN);
    if (delN.Id != null) {
        delList.add(delN);
    }
}
```

You can't delete a record that doesn't exist in the database. Checking if its Id is different of null it's a good way to know that it does.

Comment: I was adamant I tried this before posting, just tried it again and it worked. I must of typo'd or entered something in wrong. Thanks anyway!